# Why EditText in android retains its contents after orientation change whereas TextView doesn't?

Tags: android

I am quite new to android development and was playing around in android studio and found that text view is retaining any data while orientation ahange whereas a EditText retains it's data as it is.Why and how is it happening? I tried to search for the answer but could not find a satisfactory answer. Please help..

Comment: `TextView` has a method (and corresponding attribute) that sets whether its current text is saved automatically like that: [`setFreezesText()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setFreezesText(boolean)). `TextView`'s default value is `false`. `EditText`, which is a relatively small subclass of `TextView`, basically sets that value to `true`, regardless of any method or attribute value set.

Comment: So, I just have to change the default value of the method to true while defining the TextView. Thanks for such clear cut and beginner friendly explanation.

Comment: Yes, as long as it's otherwise set up to do so. That is, as long as it has a unique ID, and doesn't have any other attribute set that would disable it, like `android:saveEnabled="false"`. (Also, you can change the default value in the XML, too, btw; e.g., `android:freezesText="true"`. I don't think I made that very clear.)